# Conflict connecting to different org with same username and password

Tags: sandbox, login, enterprise

**Conflict connecting to different org with same username and password.**
Is there any other way to login to the correct org?

I am a user in two different salesforce orgs.
My profile is System Administrator in both the orgs.
In both of these orgs my username is the same somename@onecompany.com

In both of these orgs there is a sandbox named Developer. Org2 sandbox was refreshed recently, and Org1 sandbox was refreshed a few months ago.

The Developer sandbox in org1 has instance csXX so the URL is https://csXX.salesforce.com/
The Developer sandbox in org2 has instance csZZ so the URL is https://csZZ.salesforce.com/

I can successfully login to developer sandbox in  org1  https://csXX.salesforce.com/
However, when I login to developer sandbox in org2,  https://csZZ.salesforce.com/, i get connected to ORG1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In both of these orgs my username is the same somename@onecompany.com

This must be mistaken. You cannot have the same username as a full Salesforce user in two separate orgs. Your user accounts may have the same *email address*, but they certainly do not have the same user name. Note that sandbox refreshes "munge" usernames from Production; you should expect to see a suffix on the user names in those refreshed sandboxes.

Presumably Org 1 is the actual owner of this username, since that is where you are routed when you log in. Logging in via the CSXX instance assigned to a sandbox has no effect on how your log in is routed; your sandbox does not own that URL.

Comment: Exactly !  I am perplexed too, how the system allowed same username in both of the org's.  Anyways, working with the SF administrators to resolve